# Problem establishing remote DNS access to Lacie 5big Network 2

Tags: domain-name-system, remote-access, netgear

I wish to set up remote access to my Lacie 5big Network 2 storage. The 5big is connected directly to a gigabit switch. Access to the internet is gained through a Netgear DG834DV router which is also connected directly to the gigabit switch. On the network page of my Lacie dashboard I selected configure using DHCP. The IP config is as follows:

IP 192.168.0.6
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway 192.168.0.1
DNS Server 192.168.0.1

I signed up for an account with DynDNS and filled in the example.dyndns.org account details into the Lacie dashboard. My DynDNS account is pointing towards the IP address 192.0.2.5 
I also selected port forwarding on the Lacie dashboard.

When I enter www.example.dyndns.org I get a "failed to open page" message.

What am I doing wrong?

My router settings are as follows:

```
IP 192.0.2.5
PPPoE
IP Subnet Mask 255.255.255.255
Gateway 192.0.2.254 
DNS xxxxx
Attached devices - 5big 192.168.0.6
UPnP portmap table 20, 80 and 443 are all being used by  192.16.0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your device is Internet safe. Pick an extremely good password (at least 12 characters long, 3 of 4 types of characters); it should have the ability to lock out a login after X many failed login attempts. Make sure it has the latest firmware and security updates. Anything less and you're asking for some script kiddie to steal all your data, erase your device, and ransom it all back to you.

Commonly when you get a hostname from a free dns provider you don't get subdomains. So you would have to use example.dyndns.org, you can't add www or anything else on the front.

I've found UPnP to be *Flaky at Best™*. Routers usually have a port forwarding configuration where you can configure just ports 80 and 443 (HTTP and HTTPS respectively). I'm not sure why it's got port 20 in there, that's a bit odd.

Comment: Port 20 is used by FTP according to Wikipedia. Though I'm a guessing for passive mode? Normally I would just set FTP to active mode and only forward port 21.